# When synchronous api function is called , will internal function of node.js changed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js, I am trying to corelate these two features of node.js,

> node.js has two types api functions, i.e synchronous and asynchronous

> node.js support non blocking I/O

Suppose api is making synchronous call, node.js feature non blocking I/O will not be used right?

Will synchronous and asynchronous modify node.js working internally, especially the feature non blocking I/O ?

```
const fs = require('fs');
  
// Asynchronous function
fs.readFile('data.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("Below is the Data from Asynchronous function call")
  console.log(data);
});
  
// Synchronous function
var data = fs.readFileSync('data.json','utf8');
console.log("Below is the Data from Synchronous function call")
console.log(data);
```

Comment: clearly, synchronous  and "non-blocking" would be mutually exclusive terms

Comment: @Bravo Depends on what the "blocking" refers to. If it's about blocking the next statement from executing, sure, but in a (multi-threaded) program there might be other parts that are not blocked by synchronous calls. In that context, "non-blocking" might refer to anything that doesn't request a global mutex of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

In nodejs:

```
Asynchronous I/O == non-blocking I/O
Synchronous I/O == blocking I/O
```

While asynchronicity and blocking are technically not exactly the same thing, those two terms are often used interchangeably when talking about I/O operations within nodejs and that's probably because all asynchronous I/O operations in nodejs are also non-blocking and all synchronous I/O operations in nodejs are also blocking.

> Will synchronous and asynchronous modify node.js working internally

Yes, they work differently internally.

For example, asynchronous file I/O operations use a thread pool and run the file operation in a separate OS thread, leaving the Javascript thread free to do other things (run other Javascript).

Synchronous file operations do not use the thread pool.  They just call OS file operations directly which (by the design of the OS calls they use) will block the main thread until they complete.

Comment: Hi jfriend00, the concept of event loop doesn't exist in case of synchronous api call right? can you please elaborate this statement-While asynchronicity and blocking are technically not exactly the same thing. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @karthik_personal - An asynchronous I/O function call initiates the operation and then immediately returns back to the Javascript interpreter where the interpreter runs the next lines of Javascript (while the I/O operation is running).  At some future time when the I/O operation completes, it will post an event to the event queue that will be communicated back to the caller via a callback or a promise (depending upon the API).  A synchronous I/O operation just blocks and only returns back to the JS interpreter when it's done (not going through the event loop).

Comment: Thank you so much, I understood clearly :)

Comment: @karthik_personal: Please accept the answer if it solved your question...